# Create this shape in css

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

Please take a look at this image:

[image: Image example]

I apologise for my useless paint ability :-)

How can I draw that sort of shape in css, like a `)` without the use of text in a div, just **pure** css.

I have tried to make it curved like in the example, but I don't know how to curve it like that from the center.

What must I do to make this kind of shape in css?

Thanks.

Comment: This may be possible by clipping one part of an immensely enlarged letter, but other than that, this may be outside CSS's scope. Have you looked at SVG?

Comment: I have not seen that extensive behavior with CSS3, I'd look into Pekkas suggestion of using SVG.

Comment: A [Unicode undertie](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/203f/index.htm), perhaps? Of course, that's still "text in a div"....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one approach to implementing this, *but* note that any text in this element isn't going to maintain the illusion of a curve. So I'm unsure as to how useful this would be to you, but as you don't specify your use-case, it seemed worth posting as, perhaps, it might be of use in some way. If only as an idea for how you might proceed:

```
#box {
    display: block;
    margin: 2em auto;
    width: 10em;
    height: 5em;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
}

#box:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1em;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 2em;
    background-color: #fff;
    content: ' ';
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#box:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1em;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 2em;
    background-color: #000;
    content: ' ';
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/T5QW8/).

Answer (score 0):

Your example appears to resemble a chevron shape, forgive me if that's not the case, but if it is you are in luck because you can make a chevron shape using pure CSS.

```css
.chevron {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
}

.chevron:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 51%;
  background: black;
  transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
}
.chevron:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: black;
  transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="chevron"></div>
```

You can find the original example and some other shapes [here](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)